# How to close object of form created by Application.run() method in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on C# win form application.My problem is when i click on menu i created one separate thread which is showing the progress(splash progress form). When i abort thread, progress form still display..! but when i move mouse pointer over the form it disappear
immediately..!

Following is my code

```
Thread progressThread = new Thread(() => Application.Run(new frmOperationProgress()));

progressThread.IsBackground = true;
progressThread.Start();
//Some work
progressThread.Abort();
```

How to close this progress form object in c#

Answer (score 1):

The problem is using `Abort` - it's not generally recommended because there is no guarantee that it's going to do what you expect (in your case hide the form).

Best to add proper cancellation support into your thread and handle hiding the splash screen directly.

Answer (score 1):

Please never ever use Abort(). This kind of work is best done trough BackgroundWorker; if you insist on Thread

Try:

```
var form = new frmOperationProgress();
Thread progressThread = new Thread(() => Application.Run(form));
progressThread.IsBackground = true; 
progressThread.Start();
//Some work
form.ExternalClose();
```

Where ExternalClose is method of form like this:

```
public void ExternalClose() {
  if (InvokeRequired) {
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { ExternalClose(); }));
  } else {
    Close();
  }
}
```

Solution using BackgroundWorker:

In backround worker you have to do UI stuff in ProgressChanged event (which is running in UI thread) and do the dirty work in DoWork event (background thread).

FormMain.cs: (Form with single BackgroundWorker control, named "backgroundWorker1", with wired up events backgroundWorker1_DoWork, backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged and WorkerReportsProgress set to true)

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
  public partial class FormMain : Form {
    private FormProgress m_Form;
    public FormMain() {
      InitializeComponent();
      backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
      backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, "hello");
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
      backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(20, "world");
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
      backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(40, "this");
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
      backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(60, "is");
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
      backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(80, "simple");
      backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100, "end");
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
      if (e.ProgressPercentage == 0 && m_Form == null) {
        m_Form = new FormProgress();
        m_Form.Show();
      }

      if (e.ProgressPercentage == 100 && m_Form != null) {
        m_Form.Close();
        m_Form = null;
        return;
      }

      var message = (string)e.UserState;
      m_Form.UpdateProgress(e.ProgressPercentage, message);
    }
  }
}
```

Where FormProgress is simple form with ProgressBar progressBar1 and Label label1 and one extra method:

```
public void UpdateProgress(int percentage, string message) {
  this.progressBar1.Value = percentage;
  this.label1.Text = message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just close your form and the thread (which is blocked by the message loop of that form) will be ended naturally:

```
var yourForm = new frmOperationProgress();
//Start it
Thread progressThread = new Thread(() => Application.Run(yourForm));
progressThread.IsBackground = true;
progressThread.Start();
//....
//close it
yourForm.Invoke((Action)(() => yourForm.Close()));
```